# How to accept datetime irrespective of format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a web service created which will accept date time as input.

The data type i used is system.datetime.

It accepting if the input is in **mm/dd/yyyy** or **yyyy/mm/dd** but not if **dd/mm/yyyy**.

How to solve this?

Comment: You can't accept both mm/dd/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy, how would you know whether 01/02/2014 was 1st Feb 2014 or 2nd Jan 2014.

Comment: try to get only one standard input type either dd/mm/yyyy or anyone of these

Comment: The best you can do is to give a preference to mm/dd/yyyy over dd/mm/yyyy (or vice versa) to handle dates that are ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

You can use following logic

```
        string str = "26/11/2014";
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        newString = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Console.Write(newString);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

and can pass newStr to WebService Method.